# Can't display image in Django template using DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

My uploaded images are not showing when the template is rendered in the browser. 
I have set up my media url pattern like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  # App routes
  ....
]

if settings.ENV == settings.DEV:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the project settings, I have the media config like this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Here's a section of the index.html template to display the cover_image:

```
<div class="col-md-5" >
    <img src="{{ post.cover_image.url }}" class="rounded img-fluid"/>
</div>
```

When I run server the page displays properly but the cover_image doesn't appear. It only shows this:
[image]

The interesting thing is that my uploads are successful and appear in the media/images directory of the project and the terminal log shows a 200 http response but not sure why it doesn't display in the browser. I'm using Django Rest Framework and have templates for individual apps.

[image]

Here are the project settings context processors:

```
'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to determine the cause of your problem. Here are the steps you could follow to investigate:

1. Clear browser cache and reload page (just in case you see a border effect due to previous tests).
2. Check the source HTML you receive from the server, and in particular if `{{ post.cover_image.url }}` is replaced by what you expect (should be OK, since your log shows the URL of the image is requested and returns a 200 OK status code).
3. Type the URL of the image in the browser and see if it displays well. If it does, it means your HTML/CSS has something wrong (maybe because of the "rounded img-fluid" classes).
4. If 2. fails, then the image you download is probably corrupted. You need to determine if it gets corrupted during upload or download. First, check if the uploaded images are fine on the server, for example by downloading then without using Django (SFTP...).
5. If the image on the server is good, then investigate the downloaded image. Save it and try to open it with an image software. Also check the headers (wrong Content-Type?) and size of the data in the response to the image request (using the web developer tools of your browser).

Comment: 1. it's not a caching issue because I've tested on other browsers and cleared the cache

Comment: 2. the source is fine. the test image is exactly where I expected it
3. This is interesting. I inspected elements and went to the image path. Rather than seeing the image, I get directed to the homepage
4. the image doesn't get corrupted during upload because i can view it fine within the project media folder
5. I'm able to view the uploaded image by copying the link from my editor into a browser.
wonder if I'm missing another setup in Django

Comment: @MaxRah Then, you need to figure out why when fetching the image URL, Django determines that the URL matches something in your urlpatterns that returns the homepage. Try to comment lines one by one in urlpatterns (except the line for the media files) to find the faulty URL pattern.